# guide to setup crawler4j

Tags: java, web-crawler, crawler4j

I would like to setup the crawler to crawl a website, let say blog, and fetch me only the links in the website and paste the links inside a text file. Can you guide me step by step for setup the crawler? I am using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

[Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) will do everything you  need wrt html parsing. Jsoup is a java api for handling html source code. You can get

1. Table, with which you can parse each and every row or column.
2. **List of all the links** and source imports to that html(imports like
   css and js files).
3. Data of particular tag.

and more.

For your purpose, [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links) is the example code.

Hope this will help you.